# Oracle unpivot many to one

Tags: oracle

I would like to unpivot from 1 column to 3 rows and my data looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSpr6.png)

to transform to [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlTjS.png)

With this code I get 1 to 2, but not 1  to 3:
`SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT ID,
               CAT1_Y1_FACT,
               CAT1_Y2_FACT,
               CAT1_Y3_FACT,
               CAT2_Y1_FACT,
               CAT2_Y2_FACT,
               CAT2_Y3_FACT
          FROM TABLE T) UNPIVOT(CAT1_Y1_FACT FOR NBR_YEARS IN(CAT1_Y1_FACT AS 1,
                                                              CAT1_Y1_FACT AS 2,
                                                              CAT1_Y1_FACT AS 3))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNPIVOT` with multiple arguments in the `FOR ( ... ) IN` clause:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id, cat1_y1_fact, cat1_y2_fact, cat1_y3_fact, cat2_y1_fact, cat2_y2_fact, cat2_y3_fact
) AS
 SELECT LEVEL,
        100 * LEVEL + 11,
        100 * LEVEL + 12,
        100 * LEVEL + 13,
        100 * LEVEL + 21,
        100 * LEVEL + 22,
        100 * LEVEL + 23
  FROM  DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT ( fact FOR (cat, year) IN (
  cat1_y1_fact AS (1, 1),
  cat1_y2_fact AS (1, 2),
  cat1_y3_fact AS (1, 3),
  cat2_y1_fact AS (2, 1),
  cat2_y2_fact AS (2, 2),
  cat2_y3_fact AS (2, 3)
) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | CAT | YEAR | FACT
> -: | --: | ---: | ---:
>  1 |   1 |    1 |  111
>  1 |   1 |    2 |  112
>  1 |   1 |    3 |  113
>  1 |   2 |    1 |  121
>  1 |   2 |    2 |  122
>  1 |   2 |    3 |  123
>  2 |   1 |    1 |  211
>  2 |   1 |    2 |  212
>  2 |   1 |    3 |  213
>  2 |   2 |    1 |  221
>  2 |   2 |    2 |  222
>  2 |   2 |    3 |  223
>  3 |   1 |    1 |  311
>  3 |   1 |    2 |  312
>  3 |   1 |    3 |  313
>  3 |   2 |    1 |  321
>  3 |   2 |    2 |  322
>  3 |   2 |    3 |  323
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4352030d62b0300c11d7676bf2f187cb)*

---

For multiple pivot columns the syntax is given in the [Oracle `SELECT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDJBHHI):

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id, cat1_y1_fact, cat1_y2_fact, cat1_y3_fact, cat2_y1_fact, cat2_y2_fact, cat2_y3_fact,
  cat1_y1_value, cat1_y2_value, cat1_y3_value, cat2_y1_value, cat2_y2_value, cat2_y3_value
) AS
 SELECT LEVEL,
        100 * LEVEL + 11,
        100 * LEVEL + 12,
        100 * LEVEL + 13,
        100 * LEVEL + 21,
        100 * LEVEL + 22,
        100 * LEVEL + 23,
        1000 * LEVEL + 110,
        1000 * LEVEL + 120,
        1000 * LEVEL + 130,
        1000 * LEVEL + 210,
        1000 * LEVEL + 220,
        1000 * LEVEL + 230
  FROM  DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT ( (fact, value) FOR (cat, year) IN (
  (cat1_y1_fact, cat1_y1_value) AS (1, 1),
  (cat1_y2_fact, cat1_y2_value) AS (1, 2),
  (cat1_y3_fact, cat1_y3_value) AS (1, 3),
  (cat2_y1_fact, cat2_y1_value) AS (2, 1),
  (cat2_y2_fact, cat2_y2_value) AS (2, 2),
  (cat2_y3_fact, cat2_y3_value) AS (2, 3)
) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | CAT | YEAR | FACT | VALUE
> -: | --: | ---: | ---: | ----:
>  1 |   1 |    1 |  111 |  1110
>  1 |   1 |    2 |  112 |  1120
>  1 |   1 |    3 |  113 |  1130
>  1 |   2 |    1 |  121 |  1210
>  1 |   2 |    2 |  122 |  1220
>  1 |   2 |    3 |  123 |  1230
>  2 |   1 |    1 |  211 |  2110
>  2 |   1 |    2 |  212 |  2120
>  2 |   1 |    3 |  213 |  2130
>  2 |   2 |    1 |  221 |  2210
>  2 |   2 |    2 |  222 |  2220
>  2 |   2 |    3 |  223 |  2230
>  3 |   1 |    1 |  311 |  3110
>  3 |   1 |    2 |  312 |  3120
>  3 |   1 |    3 |  313 |  3130
>  3 |   2 |    1 |  321 |  3210
>  3 |   2 |    2 |  322 |  3220
>  3 |   2 |    3 |  323 |  3230
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2035fee69ee0aa062abdfb6eb8db4f5e)*

Comment: ingenious! Thanks

Comment: Hi, @kirilb you can mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem and you can mark it as useful. This is a great way to say thanks to MTO who helped you. :)

Comment: And one more question. On top of the above, there is one separate column, call it "value" which needs to be also unpivoted. Would be that like that?:
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT ( fact FOR (cat, year), value for value IN (
  cat1_y1_fact AS (1, 1,value),
  cat1_y2_fact AS (1, 2,value),
  cat1_y3_fact AS (1, 3,value),
  cat2_y1_fact AS (2, 1,value),
  cat2_y2_fact AS (2, 2,value),
  cat2_y3_fact AS (2, 3,value)
) )

Comment: @kirilb You shouldn't need to do anything to the `UNPIVOT` (except to make sure that `value` is included in the `SELECT` clause) [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=324056ed772b04b572f5b84312bc81d5)

Comment: but "value" is in fact cat1_y1_value, cat1_y2_value, cat1_y3_value and so on...

Comment: @kirilb Updated - the syntax you need is described in the Oracle documentation.